# Finding an unknown 2 x 2 matrix with a set of known vectors using QR factorization.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that we have the known 2-dimensional vectors $x_1,x_2,x_3,y_1,y_2,y_3$. Is it possible to find a 2 x 2 matrix $A$ such that $Ax_i=y_i$ using a QR factorization? Is there some way to reformat $A$ to make it possible to factorize?

Answer (score 0):

In general, no.

Pick $x_1 = y_1 = e_1$, where $e_1 = \pmatrix{1\\0}$, and $x_2 = y_2 = e_2 = \pmatrix{0\\1}$. Then the only matrix $A$ taking $x_1$ to $y_1$ and $x_2$ to $y_2$ is the $2 \times 2$ identity. By picking $x_3 = \pmatrix{1\\1}$ and $y_3$ being any vector *except* $x_3$, you get an impossible-to-solve problem.

Note that this result is independent of any notion of factorizations or methods --- it's really all about dimension and linearity.